# TreeView without checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `TreeView`-control in my form which shows a set of nested nodes. Those nodes are just options to be checked or unchecked grouped by a certain attribute present on every single node. Furthermore there´s a second `TreeView` with the same nesting, however the nodes within that list are just for information. That is user shouldn´t be able to check or uncheck them at all.

So I tried to disable the checkboxes for every node within the second tree by setting the `Checkboxes`-property to `false`. I also registered for the `BeforeCheck`-event:

```
m_treeView.BeforeCheck += m_inactiveValidationsTreeView_BeforeCheck;
m_treeView.Checkboxes = false;

// ...

private void m_inactiveValidationsTreeView_BeforeCheck(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = false;
}
```

However all items still have the checkboxes. How can I disable checkboxes for all my nodes (not just making them greyed out but just making them invisible).

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/089Rg2m21Yo/uI7NbfMupmkJ)

There is no straight way for this. A TVM_SETITEM message needs to be sent to the treeview control, set TVITEM structure's state field to 0, and TVITEM's hItem field to the treenode's handle.